# Resizable Canvas (JQuery UI)

Tags: jquery, canvas, resizable

ANY DOM element can be made resizable according to this page: http://jqueryui.com/demos/resizable/

However, it seems that this doesn't work for the CANVAS element. Possible?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Great first question!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Canvas has two types of resize behavior:

- Resizing where the contents are stretched to fit the canvas's new dimensions
- Resizing where the contents remain static while the canvas grows or shrinks

Here's a page that demonstrates the two types of "resizing": http://xavi.co/static/so-resizable-canvas.html

If you want the first type of resizing (stretch the content) then place the canvas into a container `div` and set the `width` and `height` of the canvas to 100% using CSS.  Here's what that code might look like:

```
/* The CSS */
#stretch {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

#stretch canvas {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

<!-- The markup -->
<div id="stretch"><canvas></canvas></div>

// The JavaScript
$("#stretch").resizable();
```

The second type of resizing (static content) is a two step process.  First you must adjust the `width` and `height` attributes of the canvas element.  Unfortunately, doing this clears the canvas, so you must then re-draw all its contents.  Here's bit of code that does this:

```
/* The CSS */
#resize {
    height: 100px;
    width: 200px;
}

<!-- The markup -->
<div id="resize"><canvas></canvas></div>

// The JavaScript
$("#resize").resizable({ stop: function(event, ui) {
    $("canvas", this).each(function() { 
        $(this).attr({ width: ui.size.width, height: ui.size.height });

        // Adjusting the width or height attribute clears the canvas of
        // its contents, so you are forced to redraw.
        reDraw(this);
    });
} });
```

Currently the code above re-draws the canvas's content when the user stops resizing the widget.  It's possible to re-draw the canvas on [resize](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Resizable#event-resize), however resize events occur fairly often and re-draws are expensive operations -- approach with caution.

Answer (score 1):

Well why not apply a div before the canvas element, and resize that element, and when it stops apply width and height in canvas and then redraw canvas.

Answer (score 1):

There's a bit of a funny quirk on the canvas co-ordinate system, with regards to using this :

```
#stretch canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

(from the example above)

You have to use these CSS rules because you can not specify % in the canvas' width/height attributes. But you'll find you get unexpected results when you try to draw objects on to it using just these rules- drawn objects appear squashed. Here's the above CSS, with a canvas border...

```
    /* The CSS */
    #stretch {
        width: 200px;
        height: 100px;          
    }
    #stretch canvas {
        border:1px solid red;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
```

The canvas is drawn to the right size and the border rule is implemented correctly. The blue rectangle, added in code elsewhere, is supposed to fill the canvas with a 20px padding all around, but this has not happened:

[image: using just 100% css rules]

To fix this, make sure you **also** specify a width and height for the canvas element (either in the HTML or in javascript with setAttribute):

```
canvas.setAttribute('width', '200');
canvas.setAttribute('height', '100');
```

or

```
<canvas width=200 height=100></canvas>
```

Now when I refresh the page I get what I expected:

[image]

This 'double-check' will make sure the canvas is drawn using the correct co-ordinate system and still allow it to be resized, via the CSS rules. If this is a bug, I'm sure it will be fixed in due course.

This is just about providing a fix, but you can read more in to it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretched-when-using-css-but-normal-with-width-height-properties)

Comment: P.S. Tested in the latest Chrome and latest Firefox, with identical results.