# How do I generate a thumbnail client-side in a modern browser?

Tags: html, fileapi

I'm looking for an elegant way to generate a thumbnail for use with the [FileAPI](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/). Currently I get a [DataURL](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/#readAsDataURL) representing an image. Problem is, if the image is very large, than moving it around and rerendering it becomes CPU intensive. I can see 2 options to get around this.

- Generate a thumbnail on the client
- Generate a thumbnail on the server, send the thumbnail back to the client (AJAX).

With `HTML5` we have a `canvas` element? Does anyone know how to use it to generate thumbnails from pictures? They don't have to be perfect -- sampling quality is acceptable. Is there a `jQuery` plugin that will do this for me? Are there any other way to speed up the clientside use of large images?

I'm using `HTML5`, and `Firefox 3.6+`: there is no need to support anything other than `Firefox 3.6+`, please don't provide suggestions for `IE 6.0`

Comment: Check out this question, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas

Answer (score 19):

Here’s what you can do:

```js
function getThumbnail(original, scale) {
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

  canvas.width = original.width * scale;
  canvas.height = original.height * scale;

  canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(original, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  return canvas
}
```

Now, to create thumbnails, you simply do the equivalent of this:

```js
var image = document.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
var thumbnail = getThumbnail(image, 1/5);

document.body.appendChild(thumbnail);
```

**Note:** Remember to make sure that the image is loaded (using `onload`) before trying to make a thumbnail of it.

Answer (score 11):

Okay, the way I can see this working is drawing the image to the canvas at a smaller size, then exporting the canvas. Say you want a 64px thumbnail:

```
var thumbSize = 64;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
canvas.width = thumbSize;
canvas.height = thumbSize;
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function(e) {
    c.drawImage(this, 0, 0, thumbSize, thumbSize);
    document.getElementById("thumb").src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
};
img.src = fileDataURL;
```

With this code, an image element with the id "thumb" is used as the thumbnail element. `fileDataURL` is the data URL that you got from the file API.

More information on drawing images to the canvas: http://diveintohtml5.info/canvas.html#images

And on exporting canvas data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff975241(v=vs.85).aspx