# upload a file using imageUpload (javascript), probably sthg simple

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file-upload, image-uploading

Today I upload a picture using a simple button (id: "imageUpload") to upload a file. Evthg works perfectly. A thumb of the picture is then visible in "thumb1".

I would like to upload a picture also by clicking the div "preview1".

Here is my code with what I tried :

```
<input type="file" id="imageUpload">

<div class="preview1 slide" onclick="document.getElementById('imageUpload').click();">
    <div id="thumb1" class="thumb"></div>
</div>
```

and the js :

```
new AjaxUpload('imageUpload', {
    action: "upload",
    name: 'userfile',
    onSubmit : function(file, extension){  
        do some work..  
    },
    onComplete: function(file, response) {
        do some work..
    }
});
```

Result :

When I click on "preview1", a window open to select a file : OKAY

but then the file is not uploaded (no thumb preview), and only the name of the file appear on the right of "imageUpload" :

[image]

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you are looking to have a picture thumbnail appear on file upload. This might help you

[How to generate a thumbnail image after adding an image inside an input type="file" in a form and submitting them both on the same form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500848/how-to-generate-a-thumbnail-image-after-adding-an-image-inside-an-input-type-fi)

Recycled from user: Che-azeh:

```js
function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" onchange="previewFile()"><br>
<img src="" height="200" alt="Image preview...">
```