# Javascript - Generate thumbnail from video url where store in Microsoft Azure Blob

Tags: javascript, video, thumbnails, azure-blob-storage

I use Microsoft Azure Blob Storage to stored my video.

How do I generate the thumbnail from the video's url that I get from backend using ajax.

```
axios.post('my-api')
     .then(function(response) {
        var videoUrl = response.data.url;
        // How to generate thumbnail here
     })
```

Comment: [How to Get Video Thumbnails with Javascript](http://usefulangle.com/post/46/javascript-get-video-thumbnail-image-jpeg-png).

Comment: its a backend process

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gary, I'd recommend checking this [**thread**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500848/how-to-generate-a-thumbnail-image-after-adding-an-image-inside-an-input-type-fi) which may of help to your question. using the [**following tutorial**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)

They used the following code:

```
    function previewFile() {
  var preview = document.querySelector('img');
  var file    = document.querySelector('input[type=file]').files[0];
  var reader  = new FileReader();

  reader.onloadend = function () {
    preview.src = reader.result;
  }

  if (file) {
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  } else {
    preview.src = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it working in my project, but it was too slow for loading the video