# How to display an image which i inputted

Tags: javascript, image, input, display

i made a button that takes an image as an input but i cant find a way to show the picture.
i have tried to make an empty  element and then change its URL like i saw on a different website but it didnt work.

- HTML

  ```
   <input 
       id="myImage"
       class="photo-upload"
       type="file"
       accept="image/*, image/jpeg">

       <img id="the-picture" width="200" />
  ```
- JavaScripts

  ```
   const uploadPictureButton = document.querySelector(".photo-upload");

   uploadPictureButton.addEventListener("click", displayPicture);

   function displayPicture(event) {
       let image = document.getElementById("myImage");
       image.src = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
   };
  ```

Comment: This has already been answered. [Link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16500848/how-to-generate-a-thumbnail-image-after-adding-an-image-inside-an-input-type-fi)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Preview an image before it is uploaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were some fixes required in the code, the file has to be read and the URL should be created, here is the working snippet for the code.

```js
const uploadPictureButton = document.querySelector(".photo-upload");

  uploadPictureButton.addEventListener('change', function () {
    displayPicture(this);
  });

 function displayPicture(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function (e) {
      document.getElementById('the-picture').setAttribute('src', e.target.result);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
 }
```

```html
 <input 
     id="myImage"
     class="photo-upload"
     type="file"
     accept="image/*, image/jpeg">

<img id="the-picture" width="200" />
```

Comment: i tried to run it and it works great! but i dont really understad why, can you please explain to me why did you do the:
if(uploadPictureButton)
and not just go straight to the function?

Comment: I removed that, it was not required here, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) for display an image also.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out, it works for me

`<img height="100" width="100" alt="avatar" id="imgPreview> <input type="file" onchange="document.querySelector("#imgPreview").src = window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0])">`