# Best/Fastest way to UPLOAD files

Tags: cakephp, file-upload, swfupload

My users need to upload large amounts of files to a site (only HTTP access). Also, no matter how much I tell them to shoot the pictures in low resolutions they keep coming back with Massively sized images. Obviously, they complain that it takes them to long to upload all the files thru a simple HTML form - I'm planning on switching to SWFUpload (http://www.swfupload.org/). Any other suggestions or experiences? I'm programming in LAMP using the CakePHP and jQuery frameworks - solution also needs to be browser agnostic (no ActiveX crap) and not use Java.

Comment: I'm using SWFUload and the jquery.swfupload.js plugin. There is a lot of capability here, so I'm sure it'll suit your needs. I've read that there are some Linux issues though, but these may have been sorted in more recent updates to Flash. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can see is to process the images client-side but that reduces your options to actually doing the image conversion/transformation in flash or in javascript using the html5 canvas tools.

[Resizing an image in an HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas)

^^ That doesn't look trivial and I'm not so sure canvas can manipulate images that are locally stored.

Comment: The problem with using HTML5 is that it wouldn't woork in all browsers (principally IE).

Answer (score 1):

We're using this plugin...

http://www.milesj.me/resources/script/uploader-plugin

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meioupload/

Answer (score 0):

I built a site that accepts multiple photo uploads with cakephp and the jquery swfupload plugin. It worked pretty well and I also resized the images on the fly with GD. Also, the site used Linux and I didn't have any problems.