# Can we reduce an image file size with php?

Tags: php, file-upload, filesize

Can we reduce an image file size with PHP if it exceed the the limit set by `upload_max_filesize`?

For instance, the `upload_max_filesize` at my serve is only 3MB, but the image file size for uploading is 4MB, so can I reduce 4MB to 3MB via some PHP function?

Or any other scripting programme can do this (I don't mean using Photoshop to reduce the file size)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No - it's impossible for PHP to ever get hold of that file if it is too big.

You would have to use client-size resizing, which is possible using Flash- or Java-based uploaders:

- [Compress images on client side before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607396/compress-images-on-client-side-before-uploading)
- [Image resizing client-side with javascript before upload to the server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2434458/image-resizing-client-side-with-javascript-before-upload-to-the-server)

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't. If the file size exceeds `upload_max_filesize`, PHP will just refuse the upload, so you have no opportunity to resize it.

Answer (score 0):

arnaud is correct. However, if you are able to change the upload_max_filesize, you could increase it and then resize any file that exceeds the max desired size using [gd](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php).

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `.htaccess` file, put this:

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 4194288
php_value post_max_size 4194288
```

4194288 = 4MB