# How do I compress image on client side in blueimp:- not resize

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, blueimp

I am using blueimp https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload image plugin, my clients will be uploading very high resolution images, hence it will take many hours but we like to have client side compression (not resize) as they have different aspect ratio and we cannot spoil that. I tried many ways but couldn't get it right. Any ideas?

I am using it in PHP
Adding any other code or script results into errors in blueimp

Comment: Define `very high resolution images`. I have a 30kx30k render which is 56MB big and uploads fine in a couple of minutes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compress an image via Javascript in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672746/how-to-compress-an-image-via-javascript-in-the-browser)

Comment: This will be helpful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607396/compress-images-on-client-side-before-uploading