# Error while using JIC for image compression in client-side

Tags: javascript, client-side, image-compression

Using a solution in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607396/compress-images-on-client-side-before-uploading) by brunobar79. My problem is that I am getting the following error;

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on
> 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type
> '(CSSImageValue or HTMLImageElement or SVGImageElement or
> HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap or
> OffscreenCanvas)'

My JS;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jic = {
        compress: function(source_img_obj, quality, output_format){

             var mime_type = "image/jpeg";
             if(typeof output_format !== "undefined" && output_format=="png"){
                mime_type = "image/png";
             };

             var cvs = document.createElement('canvas');
             cvs.width = source_img_obj.naturalWidth;
             cvs.height = source_img_obj.naturalHeight;
             var ctx = cvs.getContext("2d").drawImage(source_img_obj, 0, 0);
             var newImageData = cvs.toDataURL(mime_type, quality/100);
             var result_image_obj = new Image();
             result_image_obj.src = newImageData;
             return result_image_obj;
        },
}
function myFunction(){
    var source_img = document.getElementById("source_img"),
        target_img = document.getElementById("target_img");
    var quality =  80,
    output_format = 'jpg';
    target_img.src = jic.compress(source_img,quality,output_format).src;
    console.log("I am a myFunction!");
};
</script>
```

snippet of my HTML;

```
<form>   <img src="" id="target_img"> </form>
<button onclick="myFunction()" >compress</button>
```

Another developer has added the HTML/Python code hence not really sure what to add here from that. The `<form>` has `source_img` defined as an ID in it.

The client's requirement is that when an image, once selected, should get compressed and then placed in `<img>` after the compress button is clicked.This is the first time I am using image compression using JS in the client-side and I am considerably new to JS. Please advise.