# Nativescript saveToFile is slow when file size is bigger

Tags: javascript, nativescript

I'm using `nativescrip-background-http` plugin to upload images to a remote server.

The idea is that I use `nativescript-imagepicker` plugin to select the image, save it to a folder using `saveToFile` then upload it.

saveToFile works well with smaller files but there's a lug when the file size is big. Is there a way to reduce file size before saving it?

Comment: Is there a way of uploading the image without necessarily saving it first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to circumnavigate the issue by setting the image height, width and quality using `getImage()` as shown bellow.

```
getImage({maxWidth: 200, maxHeight: 200, quality: 100})
```

This makes all files saved using `saveToFile` method of a uniform quality thus no lugging while dealing with large or smaller files. A better suggestion would be great though.

Answer (score 0):

You can check this [Compress images on client side before uploading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5607396/compress-images-on-client-side-before-uploading). But you will lose some data while compressing.

In the case of image, it will be the resolution.