# Quality of scaled images worse in IE8/9, than in IE7

Tags: image, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-9, internet-explorer-7, scale

Try opening [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/image-rendering#Live_Examples) in IE7 and IE9.

As the page mentions, it uses `-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic`.

I've read that this setting has been disabled in IE8/9 because it is now the default style (in IE7, nearest-neighbor was the default interpolation mode).

However, the image quality in IE8/9 is much worse than in IE7, as shown here:

[image: example]

What gives?  Is there a way to get better scaled down images in IE8/9?

Comment: Weird.  I've tried it in IE9 on Windows 2008 Server, and had a colleague try it out in IE9 on his Windows 7 laptop as well.  I'm definitely seeing the image quality as poor.  I also tried turning compatibility view on/off, and that made no difference.

Comment: Found a couple of other people having the same issue:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9945363/image-scaling-causes-poor-quality-in-firefox-internet-explorer-but-not-chrome

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6126817/poor-quality-downsized-image-in-ie9

Comment: Did you specifically try the hat image in the URL I provided?

Comment: use image size as it is, do not minimize or increase the size of original.

Answer (score 1):

Use the CSS fit-and-shrink technique, demonstrated here:

- [CSS fit-and-shrink demo](http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/fast.html)

It basically layers two copies of the image, one with a fixed width and one with a fixed height, to preserve the aspect ratio.