# Canvas - Image resize and copy into another

Tags: image, html, canvas

Is there a jQuery plugin or code with which I could resize an image (or canvas (with this image)) and copy that into another image (or canvas)?
Picture #2 is a

EDIT:
Idea: Maybe make use of `-moz-transform: scale(sx, sy)`/`-webkit-transform: scale(sx, sy)`?
Or this [Resizing an image in an HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas)

[image]

Comment: Why are you doing this? Why not resize just with CSS?

Comment: The user should be able to resize the image.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can resize-and-copy an image or canvas into another canvas easily.

`context.drawImage(image, dx, dy, dw, dh)` allows you to resize any image (or canvas) you want to draw as you draw it.

You can draw a 100x100 image as 50x50 or 200x200.

There is additionally `context.drawImage(image, sx, sy, sw, sh, dx, dy, dw, dh)` if you only want to draw a portion of the original image.

[image: from Canvas Spec]

You want the drawn images to be resizable and movable? That's a whole 'nother can of worms, such functionality is not built in to canvas in the least, meaning you'll have to make it. I wrote a small tutorial on getting [resizable, movable objects in the canvas](http://simonsarris.com/blog/225-canvas-selecting-resizing-shape), which is a good place to start.