# copy & stretch part of canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I use three canvas' over each other to draw a map for a robot application. The map gets constantly updated (on pixel level) based on the robots sensor results.
I now want a part of this map to be displayed in a zoomed way at a diffent place on the page.
Aim is to have a zoomed view of the robots actual position drawn above the complete map.

What is the best/easiest approach for this?

Thanks
Robert

Comment: Do you want a proper zoom, or just a texture stretch?

Comment: Honestly - I don't know the difference. I know that the Quality will decrease. So there will not be more information just because I zoom in.
I just want to see the robot and its surrounding in a bigger size as the size is too small on the complete map to see details. Quality doesn’t matter.

Not knowing the difference I would say – whatever is simpler.

Comment: OK.Just found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7423754/canvas-image-resize-and-copy-into-another