# How many arguments to setTimeout?

Tags: javascript

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3223466/765287) makes a call to `setTimeout` with four arguments.

```
 setTimeout(self.process1, 0, self, u);
```

This confuses me.  The [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp) I've seen for `setTimeout` only uses two arguments, not four.

What do the last two arguments do?

Comment: lol... He is calling  w3schools article as documentation! See http://www.w3fools.com

Comment: Huh... I w3schools was recommended to me in university (15 years ago). I'd always assumed they were associated with the W3C, and figured they were reputable. Thanks for the w3fools.com link!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting the [documentation on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout):

> **Syntax**
>
> ```
> var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
> ```
>
> Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first
>   syntax does not work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Ah, thanks.  I'm new to Javascript and didn't think to check MDN. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This function has two signatures

```
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(func, delay, [param1, param2, ...]);
var timeoutID = window.setTimeout(code, delay);
```

Note that passing additional parameters to the function in the first syntax does not work in Internet Explorer.

Note found in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) in regards to what these extra parameters are for:

> Prior to Gecko 13 (Firefox 13.0 / Thunderbird 13.0) , Gecko passed an
>   extra parameter to the callback routine, indicating the "actual
>   lateness" of the timeout in milliseconds. This non-standard parameter
>   is no longer passed.

The first signature (with more than two params) is not supported by all browsers so my personal recommendation is to avoid it.