# it's taking too long to upload image to server in PHONEGAP

Tags: html, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am new to phonegap. In my app, i am trying to upload photo as a profile picture, and it is stored in server. Whenever i upload a picture,It gets uploaded but when i click on save option it will take sometime to finish the process and navigate to other page. How can i solve this? Is there any particular solution to compress image and upload to the server without loosing its clarity? And i have used this to upload image : http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap allows you to specify a quality level when you retrieve your picture, which will significantly impact the size of the file you will then have to upload

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 50 });
```

Another solution is to use the HTML5 canvas to resize your picture before sending it (many references on the subject, for instance a very detailed one with complete control on resampling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas))

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for late reply!!But setting quality never worked...So now i am trying it using Html5 canvas method..

Answer (score 0):

After reading several answers, the solution that worked for me was adding this line to camera's options:

```
correctOrientation : true
```

here is my code:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessPhoto, onFailPhoto, {
    quality: 20,
    targetWidth: 512,
    targetHeight: 512,
    destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URL,
    correctOrientation : true
});
```