# Pre-compress images on mobile devices

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, html, mobile

I'm working on a Web application that allows images to be uploaded to the server, but the pictures take quite some some time to upload via 3g/h. I'm wondering is there some kind of way to pre-compress the image on taking or uploading them?

For example, the user takes a picture at 3g/h, depending on the camera about 2 - 3 mb, and starts the upload. It takes a while or the connection breaks at a 3g - g - h or whatever switch or drop. The browser doesn't take that well, and the image can and will be lost.

Any advice please. :)

PS. I'm talking about a cross (mobile) browser / cross (mobile) platform

Comment: you can use a canvas tag to resize an image into a jpeg dataURL of custom jpeg quality, which can then be uploaded.

Comment: Have you looked into canvas? There's still mixed support for this on the desktop, so you've got your work cut out for mobile I'm afraid.

Comment: I guess you could always draw the image to a canvas, before resizing/encoding it. Problem is though, that you get back a base64 encoded string, which actually takes slightly more space to store. If the browser gzips the response, it can be comparable, but I don't think it ever gets any better(than the size of the original image) Only (unpalatable?) option I can think of is a native-app that runs on the mobile devices, thus giving you access to libjpeg libpng zlib etc, etc. Shame the network infrastructure is so crappy where you and your visitors live. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas). You mention cross browser/cross mobile platform which assumes a non-native application using C#/C++. If you did develop a client mobile application natively you would have access to the necessary image libraries (GD) to compress the images (without resizing them) that you wish.