# How to improve low quality canvas image on resize?

Tags: jquery, canvas, image-quality

I am using `canvas` to resize an image but resized image is low quality.[Example is here](http://jsfiddle.net/a5tpc/1/)

I searched on google but did not find any easy to understand and straight forward answer.

Please provide a working solution.

Here is my code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var canvas2=document.getElementById("canvas1");
   var ctx=canvas2.getContext("2d");
   ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById("img1"),0,0,200,150);
});
```

Comment: Sharing a fiddle is a good start but it doesn't seem to show your problem.

Comment: @Riateche: It does not solve problem. You can try it in fiddle.

Comment: Well, I think it's hard to solve this problem in all browsers, since there is no standard way to set antialiasing options for `drawImage`. For example, see this [Chromium issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=7508) about this problem. It's not fixed yet, and there is no solution in comments. Maybe you should let the server do the hard work and resize the image?

Comment: Have a look here too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas