# Jquery, resize data of an image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I have a script for resize an image.

So, for begin, i have an image with : `height=600px` and `width=500px`

After I use my script, and a resize this image to to, for example : `height=300px` and `width=250px`.

I use :

```
$('#image').css("width", varvar);
$('#image').css("height", varvarvar);
```

But if i look my image with firebug, the data is always to the originale size (600 and 500), how can i resize the data (src) a my image with jquery ?

Comment: If you wish to edit the source image and save it on your server you'll need PHP in stead of Jquery. Jquery only works on client side.

Comment: I need to resize the image data with javascript, because after that i have a module for select just a part of this image (jcrop)

Comment: How about getElementById('image').width = varvar

Comment: Then you have to save the image to the server first with PHP. Then load the newly created image in JCROP.

Comment: or if you dont know php there are other languages... 
if(php != the_internet){ ClapYourHands(); } *clap clap*

Comment: There is no way to resize an image data with javascript, jquery, a plugin ... don't know ? without php

Comment: You can resize an image client side using a canvas, like explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly

Comment: @ClémentAndraud i would use c# and .net... php is one solution but there are others.

Comment: there is one particular js plugin which u could use to do so,**http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php**

Comment: @ClémentAndraud Let me know if my answer below answers your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As thoroughly mentioned in the comments, there's no way to change the original size (as in, the amount of data) of an image with client-side scripting. The issue being that the image is hosted on the server-side and any javascript manipulation remains strictly client-side. If you want to commit some sort of data change, that would require server-side scripting, such as PHP (although there are many other alternatives..)

Basically, the idea is that the client sends a request for image manipulation to the server, who then runs some sort of script to alter the original image data and replaces the original file on the server. On page refresh, the image would have changed.

Comment: Is that possible with ajax, to call a php script, resize my image with php, return a new image base64, and put this new image in my src attribut ? i don't want a refresh

Comment: @ClémentAndraud - If you have the image on the server, why don't you rescale it before using it in the first place?

Comment: i dont think so, nailthumb actually allows you to resize the images to whatever size without losing the pixels. **http://www.garralab.com/nailthumb.php**

Comment: I don't have the image on my server. I get this image with a upload form, i need to resize and do some stuff before save

Comment: The browser doesn't have manipulation access to files on your computer. You'd have to upload it and manipulate it server-side.

Answer (score 0):

When you use .css you are changing the style attribute of the image. If you want to change its width and height attributes you have to do this like so:

```
var img = document.getElementById('image'), height = 25, width = 50;
    img.width = width;
    img.height = height;
```

Then when you inspect the element you will see its width and height attributes changed.
But this is only on the browser. It will not change its width and height permanently. You could however convert it to Base64 and send it to your server. But you would have to use HTML5 canvas. I can show you how to do that if needed.