# resize image using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using javascript function to input image.

This is my HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="filUpload" id="filUpload" onclick="" onchange="showimagepreview(this)">
<br />
<div id="before">
<img id="imgprvw" alt="" class="img-thumbnail" style="width: 250px; height: 250px;" />
```

And this is my JavaScript:

```
function showimagepreview(input) { //image preview after select image
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var filerdr = new FileReader();
    filerdr.onload = function(e) {
      url = e.target.result;
      image = url;
      $('#imgprvw').attr('src', url);
      //console.log(url);

      //$('#imgprvw').attr('src', e.target.result);
      //url = e.target.result;
      //$("#imgpath").val(url);
    }
    filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

This code convert image to bite array, I need to resize my image using that bite array. Is there any possible methods to do it.

I will pass that binary array to web service. I the image size too high, it takes much time, that's why I need to convert.

Comment: If you actually want to resize the image (and not just change the size on the site), maybe check out resizing via canvas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly
But generally I would do that on the backend.

Comment: i will pass that binary array to web service. if the image size too high, it takes much time, that's why i need co convert.

Comment: Yes, then resize it via canvas. You can use `document.getElementById("mycanvas").toDataURL('image/png');` to get the PNG as a data-url afterwards.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resize image with javascript canvas (smoothly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly/53986239#53986239

Comment: This answer explains very clearly how to do it.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly/53986239#53986239](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly/53986239#53986239)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resize it on the canvas like this:

```
function showimagepreview(input) { //image preview after select image
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var filerdr = new FileReader();

    filerdr.onload = function(e) {
      var img = new Image();

      img.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        canvas.width = 250;
        canvas.height = canvas.width * (img.height / img.width);
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

        // SEND THIS DATA TO WHEREVER YOU NEED IT
        var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');

        $('#imgprvw').attr('src', img.src);
        //$('#imgprvw').attr('src', data);//converted image in variable 'data'
      }
      img.src = e.target.result;
    }
    filerdr.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
  }
}
```

I haven't tested this yet, but it should work.

[Resize image with javascript canvas (smoothly)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly)

Comment: You tried to linked the question [Resize image with javascript canvas (smoothly)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19262385/1960455), but it was not visible the that way. As a note: this question very similar to the linked one, so it should probably be better marked as duplicate.

Comment: It's similar, but it didn't include file upload and adding the loaded image to a canvas. Thanks for the code clean-up though. I didn't find an easy way to indent.

Comment: I understand your point and I might be wrong about it: But creating answers over and over again, that are just slightly different, is not that helpful to keep SO clear. The question is about resizing and not "How to draw data that was read by FileReader as image into a canvas" or something like this. While the OP might not know how to do that it should be a different question IMHO.

Comment: data in img.src is not converted data. but there is some values in var data. but i can't identify what value is this.

Comment: t.niese, you do have a point. Can you mark it as duplicate?
Saranga, the value in `data` is base64 encoded. You should be able to use it as per your edit. Does it work?

Comment: i'd try to use, converted image display on canvas, but value in data can't be decord using decoder. but value goes to database and can retrieve from database.