# How can I use createImageBitmap with raw data as input rather then an image

Tags: javascript, canvas, imagebitmap

I am writing a data viz app that requires me to process very large 2D arrays of data and convert that data into a scaled down image for display in a canvas in the DOM.

I am bumping up against DOM canvas size limitations. My arrays can be as large as 5000 x 5000. I want to get around the canvas size limitation by using `createImageBitmap()` to simultaneously scale down and convert the large array to an `ImageBitMap` of smaller size - 256 x 256 - for insertion into an onscreen canvas.

How can I convert the raw array data into the proper format? Will this approach work?

Comment: what is the raw data that you have in your 2D array, can you elaborate on that?

Comment: It is a bit hard to isolate. My current approach is: 1) Draw array into OffScreenCanvas of identical size. 2) call drawImage() on the smaller destination canvas - 256 x 256 which performs both to minify and to copy. For an array large then about 4K x 4K the destination canvas is never written. No error. Below that size it works fine.

Comment: You could potentially reduce the data algorithmicly, it's a bit of a step away from what you currently have, but e.g. averaging each 2x2 block of pixels down to a single pixel worth of colour would quarter the number of pixels.

Comment: Yes I agree. The "proper" approach would be to downsample the array data and just hand it to the destination canvas. I am hoping to get "free" downsampling using imaging functionality rather then rolling my own,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create and manipulate your image before rendering it to canvas. 5000x5000 shouldn't be too large for canvas though. What limitations are you running into? Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27123116/2244284) covers resizing as on canvas then grabbing data.

```
var raw = new Uint8ClampedArray(5000*5000*4); // 4 for RBGA
var imageData = new ImageData(raw, 5000,5000);
var bitmap = createImageBitmap(imageData);
```

Comment: Nice. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Works great. Cheers.

Comment: And orders of magnitude faster than using drawImage(). Wow!

Comment: Just a note, ImageData constructor has [the same size limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6081483/maximum-size-of-a-canvas-element) than HTMLCanvasElement. So indeed for 5K*5K it should be ok, and even a good alternative, but the question asked about working around these limits, and this solution won't do. cc @dugla

Comment: Good to know Kaido. You are correct, it is still an open question why my original implementation was not working. For one of the user's of my app their browser - Chrome I believe - crashed. With Gavin's approach speed is up 20x - on the down sampling - and mems usage is way down.