# Taking in an image file, modifying the image size, then return the new image file

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

On the client side, I am trying to have the user supply an image from their local environment, process that image by reducing it's size, then return the new image file (with the reduced size) to my server for storage.

I was wondering how this could be done.  All I could find was obvious information on modifying the size of an image displayed, but not any information modifying the size of an image and then creating a new file for that reduced size image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10673122/how-to-save-canvas-as-an-image-with-canvas-todataurl

Comment: Please see:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly