# HTML a tag to resize and save image

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have an image of `500x500` pixels and I want to resize it to let's say `200x200` pixels. I use:

```
<a download="mypic.png" href="mypic.png" title="ImageName">
    <img alt="ImageName" src="mypic.png" width=200>
</a>
```

And I am trying to make it save the above image with the new dimensions but when I click it it saves it with the original ones... How can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly

Comment: using "width" only resize the rendered image on web browser. the image is still the same size as it really is.

Comment: You have edited your question but i have provided the solution below. The answer still remains the same.

Answer (score 2):

You are resizing the image using css (this is client side) so you have resized it in your browser window to 200px but that has not physically changed the server image.

The download link will just download the original which is at normal size.

To change the size on the server side you would need a server, and the code/system to resize the image, Which for a newbie such as yourself would be a tall order.

Their are other ways of doing this but without knowing your use case it's impossible to advise.

One solution would be some sort of online image resize api that you could wrap your image url in and it would manipulate it for you.

such as

http://rsz.io/

This should allow you to add a new url they provide that includes your url and they would do the resize for you for free as follows

```
<a href="https://i.pinimg.com.rsz.io/originals/e6/9e/50/e69e504fa3ad6c5a5ded9ec199795fa7.jpg?width=200" download>Save!</a>
```

Acording to there docs you just add rsz.io to your image url and then use ? to apply methods they have such as width=200 see there docs above for details.

I'm not an affiliate or related to the service.

Comment: If you are going to downvote an answer at least give a reason why  - the answer offers a perfectly appropriate explanation to the problem as well as a solution -