# Resize and compress image quality before upload in Firebase with Angular

Tags: angular, image, typescript

In my app an user can submit a photo that will be uploaded into **Firebase Storage**. I need to resize and compress the photo quality (without ruining it) to not take up much space in the storage and to speed up the upload an retrieve process.

How can I do? advices?

This is my `selectPhoto.ts` code that choose the photo that I will upload!

```
selectPhoto_phone(){
    this.camera.getPicture({
      sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY, 
      destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
      quality: 100,
      encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.PNG,
    }).then(imageData => {

      this.isEnabled = true;
      this.myPhoto = imageData;
    }, error => {

      this.isEnabled = false;
      console.log("ERROR -> " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
  }
```

Comment: you can ask for a lower `quality` by giving a smaller number to the quality param. Mind the quirks though. https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera#cameraoptions-errata-

Comment: otherwises you could use a browser based solution like this maybe? if you use ionic for example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly

Comment: thank tou @toskv , I'll check your links!

Answer (score 0):

Use the https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/camera/

There is a *quality* option expecting values 0-100 with default 50 that will provide a compressed image.

```
const options: CameraOptions = {
  quality: 40, //change this value
  destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
  encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
  mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE
}

this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
 // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
 // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
 let base64Image = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData;
}, (err) => {
 // Handle error
});
```

Hope it helps :)