# Is there a way to turn a cropped image into a file object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, image, base64, blob

I have this line of code

```
var cropped_image = canvas.toDataURL();
```

That is turning the canvas image into a string like .

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA..............
```

I am wanting this to be a file object.Like when you upload a file as part of

```
input type="file" accept="image/*" id="file"   name="file"
```

What kind of string is `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAA`

Is there a way to turn that into a file object or a base64 string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53525555/1169519

Comment: *a way to turn that into a ... base64 string* - `iVBORw....` is a base64 string of a PNG.