# Resizing Image in Javascript Using its URL Alone - Backbone.Js

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

Consider the following code:

```
if (realNodeType === 'custom') {
    let icon = '/icon/custom/' + item.get('icon') + '.png';
    let iconUrl = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.host + '/' + window.location.pathname.split('/')[1] + icon;
    treeNodeMap[parentLabel].get('nodes').add(new Backbone.Model({
        id: item.get('id'),
        name: item.get('name'),
        icon: iconUrl
    }));
}
```

`icon` returns the url of the image I'm looking for. The only problem is that I'm getting it in a slightly bigger dimension (21x21). What I would like to do is to resize it once I get it to (16x16). Is this possible?

I thought about adding another field `success` like this:

```
    ...
    id: item.get('id'),
    name: item.get('name'),
    icon: iconUrl,
    success: function(icon){
    //resizing goes here
    }
```

However, I'm unable to access the image's height and width using that method.

Comment: Can you not just use CSS to set the size of the icon?  It will obviously still be 21x21 but you could just display it as 16x16

Comment: Thanks for your time. Unfortunately, using CSS is not an option here. There's no way it can be resized using js?

Comment: Yes, you can.  It just seems overkill, but here's a link...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly

Comment: Thank you. I'll look into it.