# Blurry Image on canvas

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

Drawing the image on canvas makes it very blurry. But as the image is scaled up it gets crisp. I cannot figure out the problem.

image I am using : https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512819432727-dbcb57a06f13?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80

codepen link : https://codepen.io/AdnanHashmi/pen/eYNQPoX

Even zooming in on the page shows that the image drawn on canvas is blurred and smugged.

This is how it looks.
[image: Helo]The left image here is the image drawn on canvas while the right one is put on the screen using  tag.

My code:

```js
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var dpi = window.devicePixelRatio;
var img = new Image();
img.src =
  "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512819432727-dbcb57a06f13?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80";
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.style.width = canvas.width.toString() + "px";
canvas.style.height = canvas.height.toString() + "px";

img.onload = () => {
  var newWidth = canvas.width * dpi;
  var newHeight = canvas.height * dpi;

  canvas.style.width = newWidth.toString() + "px";
  canvas.style.height = newHeight.toString() + "px";

  ctx.drawImage(img, 100, 100, 100, 150);
};
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

canvas {
  image-rendering: pixelated;
}

img[src$=".gif"],
img[src$=".png"] {
  image-rendering: -moz-crisp-edges; /* Firefox */
  image-rendering: -o-crisp-edges; /* Opera */
  image-rendering: -webkit-optimize-contrast; /* Webkit (non-standard naming) */
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
  -ms-interpolation-mode: nearest-neighbor; /* IE (non-standard property) */
}

.sharp {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100px;
  left: 250px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 150px;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
<img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512819432727-dbcb57a06f13?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=634&q=80" class="sharp" alt="" srcset="">
```

Comment: You should not "scale" canvas by setting the size style properties. Take a look at [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/transform)

Comment: What should I set the parameters of the transform to. The dpi calculated? I am not getting how transform needs to applied in the code i provided above.

Comment: Does not look blurry, there are a few artifacts but certainly no blur

Comment: @HelderSepulveda It is blurry. I will attach a picture with the post. You can check for youserlf too. Open the codepen link i have provided and zoom in using chrome zoom in tool. You will see the difference

Comment: I'm not sure what sizes you're trying to change. Use `canvas.width` and `canvas,height` to resize the canvas itself. When you want to [resize](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)  the image you're just about to draw, use `dWidth` and `dHeight` arguments to define the new size. If you want to scale an existing canvas, use `transform` matrix or [`scale`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale), but __never__ use CSS styles for sizing of canvases.

Comment: After you've got the scaling/resizing corrected, and if the image is still blurry, take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262141/resize-image-with-javascript-canvas-smoothly). Also, [MDN's Canvas Tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial) is good reading ...

Comment: Adnan, I did check before I posted my comment, it was not blurry then and your image now is not blurry, what you see are artifacts from scaling and zooming in the page, 100% expected

Comment: will drawing an svg instead of png yield better results?