# How to give an Image variable a max width?

Tags: javascript, image

I have a file input that only accepts images. When the image loads, I add it to an `Image` variable.
I'm trying to make the image have a max width. Here's my code:

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

reader.onload = function (loadEvt) {
    var newImage = new Image();
    newImage.src = loadEvt.target.result;

    // do something with newImage
};
```

I tried doing: `new Image(200, 'auto');` but it didn't keep the aspect ratio. How can I give a max width while still keeping the images original aspect ratio?

Comment: One option is to use `width` and `height` attribute in `<img>` tag that will make it look different dimensions, but if you want to truly change image dimensions it can be done with canvas https://stackoverflow.com/q/19262141/6160662

Comment: Just a tip: `newImage = URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0])`

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);

reader.onload = function (loadEvt) {
    var newImage = new Image(200);
    //if you only set width,height may auto.else height is so
    newImage.src = loadEvt.target.result;

    // do something with newImage
};
```

you can run code on https://codepen.io/wzc570738205/pen/gOPPNvo?editors=1010

Comment: It came out stretched