# HTML5 Canvas Pixelation When Positioning and Combining Images

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

Using GameAlchemist's brilliant code found in [HTML5 Canvas Resize (Downscale) Image High Quality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922880/html5-canvas-resize-downscale-image-high-quality), I successfully scaled down an image with excellent fidelity.

The referenced answer returns a new canvas. If I take that canvas and write it to an existing canvas using drawImage() or putImageData() at the top-left corner (i.e. (0,0)), it looks great.  As soon as I try to centre the image within an existing (larger) canvas, however, it becomes pixelated, though not as bad as it does when I allow the canvas to scale it down and centre it.

Is there a way to place images anywhere in the canvas without pixelation?

For example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("imageContainer");
canvas.setAttribute("height", 500);
canvas.setAttribute("width", 500);
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var image = new Image();
image.src = some_url;
// see linked answer for downScaleImage()
var newcanvas = downScaleImage(image, 0.2);
// this is vertically centred but pixelated
// ctx.drawImage(newcanvas, 0, Math.round((canvas.height-newcanvas.height)/2));
// this is at the top-left corner but beautiful
ctx.drawImage(newcanvas, 0, 0);
```

Also, short of having multiple, small canvases, is there a way to combine high-quality images into a single canvas without pixelation occurring?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you add a code sample? Thank you

Comment: How big is the image from `some_url` (approximately)?

Comment: It's a 1,586 KB PNG before being scaled down.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not sure why this would be happening. Maybe you could post some example images as well.