# Change natural size of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, image-resizing

I want to resize (crop) an image (change natural size of image) and show it to a user.  How can this be done with jquery or javascript?

My goal is to reduce the size of my image.

**EX:** If my image size is: `900 kb` i want reduce to: `200 kb`, with crop(resize width and height)

Please give me a example on: http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

This stuff is advenced.
Chack this:
[HTML5 Canvas Resize (Downscale) Image High Quality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922880/html5-canvas-resize-downscale-image-high-quality)

You can also check this out: https://transloadit.com/

Comment: I tried use of transloadit plugin for change natural size of image and show it to a user , but it doesn't work for me. how can done it?