PHP Imagick - Scale Image - output not satisfying
I'm trying to scale a png image. The top most is scaled by the browser (so on client side):
<img src="data:image/png;base64,{articleImage.fileContent}" style="max-width: 200px; max-height: 200px;" />

The bottom one is scaled by PHP Imagick (so on server side):
$image->resizeImage($newWidth, $newHeight, Imagick::FILTER_BOX, 1);

The scaled output is not satisfying to me. I played a lot with Imagick:FILTER_ and blur factor (1) - but didn't achieved a good result. Any hint from your side? Thank you!


Processing images is more than just the resize operation. Please post the original image, and the full PHP code you use to process it, including the output stage. That way readers can see for themselves what happens when your code is applied. An image is nice, but nothing beats reproducing the result yourself.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31077776/what-algorithm-do-browsers-commonly-use-when-scaling-images-with-css

This question is similar to: Resize image in PHP. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
