# Blur effect with covolution matrix

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, blur, convolution

I have a canvas and an image on it and I am trying to apply a blur effect on it.I know the form of the convolution matrix for blurring, but I do not know how to make the mathematical operations with it and with the pixels.
Could someone help, please?

```
convM=[1/9, 1/9, 1/9,1/9, 1/9, 1/9,1/9, 1/9, 1/9];
var imgE = ctx.getImageData(0,0,300,200);
var pix = imgE.data;
for (var i = 0;i < pix.length; i += 4) {
       //for each color channel             
}
imgE.data=pix;
ctx.putImageData(imgE, 0,0);
```

Comment: Can you share the full code that you are working with ?

Comment: Sorry, I know that it is recommended to share the full code, but this it just a small part of a large project and I cannot share the code on the internet.

Comment: [Here's one way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19235791/1693593) to apply convolutions, just replace the convolution matrix with one for blur (instead of sharpen as in the link).

Comment: It's not recommended to share the full code: [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)