# drawImage() is not working

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, requestanimationframe

When I open the html file in chrome, I only see the background, I open the consol and I see "hi" ever frame but I cant see the Image that I "drew" using the drawImage() `

```js
var ctx = document.querySelector('Canvas').getContext('2d')

function draw() {
  ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('Mario'), 50, 61, 0, 0)
  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw)
  console.log('hi')
}
draw()
```

```css
#Canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(Pictures/Background.jpg);
  margin: -8px;
}
```

```html
<canvas id='Canvas'></canvas>
<div style='display:none;'>
  <img id='Mario' src='Pictures/Mario.png'>
</div>
```

Comment: Bad selector, for starters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('Mario'), 50, 61, 0, 0);
```

You've got your image width and height set to `0`.  Switch it to this instead:

```
ctx.drawImage(document.getElementById('Mario'), 0, 0, 50, 61);
```

Comment: Sorry, I had the mistake and correction switched.  It should work.  Check the fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tceqmprx/1/

Comment: Okay, it worked but why does the picture quality look so poor?

Comment: If you mean in my example, it's because the pixel size doesn't match the dimensions passed into `drawImage()`

Comment: No I mean in my picture everything looks bad

Comment: Maybe it got somehing to do with the window.requestAnimationFrame because it starts out good and than it get worse

Comment: and every time I make the picture bigger it gets better

Comment: What are the actual pixel dimensions of your image?  Ideally, you should display the image at it's actual pixel size.  If that's not an option for whatever reason, and you have to downsize the image in the canvas, then see GameAlchemist's answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922880/html5-canvas-resize-downscale-image-high-quality

Comment: No I have the exact same size, here is a zip file on google drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dvTJndbEf3Hfp-k8aeaWaiytxIJ3l45h/view?usp=sharing
and why can I not use more than one key at once?