# How to generate thumbnails of Images/ Videos on frontend?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, jsx

I am working on a reactJS project I want to generate thumbnails of videos and images (same image with low size) on the frontend side, without using any backend service, is there any library available or any other method?
Thanks

Comment: FYI: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18922880/1207049

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is YES. You need to look for something called `canvas`. There are a few libraries out there for doing this like the below one.

https://github.com/brothatru/react-video-thumbnail

But if you are going to build it yourself, as I said you need to search for `create thumbnail from image/video`

Comment: i did that now the problem is i am not able to use toDataURL() function as i want to send that thumbnail to a backend api. is there any suggestions you may give?