# Fast resampling of `UInt8ClampedArray` image data via webassembly

Tags: javascript, c, canvas, webassembly

I am using a [Hermite-filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922880/html5-canvas-resize-downscale-image-high-quality/19223362#19223362) to resize an image on a canvas.

To make it even faster, I thought about rewriting it in C and then compiling to WASM and using the wasm code to resize the image.

The C code looks like this:

```
// hermite_resample.c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <math.h>

void hermite_resample(const uint8_t* imageData, uint8_t* outputData, int width_source, int height_source, int newWidth, int newHeight) {
    double ratio_w = (double)width_source / newWidth;
    double ratio_h = (double)height_source / newHeight;
    int ratio_w_half = (int)ceil(ratio_w / 2);
    int ratio_h_half = (int)ceil(ratio_h / 2);

    for (int j = 0; j < newHeight; j++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < newWidth; i++) {
            int x2 = (i + j * newWidth) * 4;
            double weight = 0;
            double weights = 0;
            double weights_alpha = 0;
            double gx_r = 0;
            double gx_g = 0;
            double gx_b = 0;
            double gx_a = 0;
            double center_y = (j + 0.5) * ratio_h;
            int yy_start = (int)floor(j * ratio_h);
            int yy_stop = (int)ceil((j + 1) * ratio_h);
            for (int yy = yy_start; yy < yy_stop; yy++) {
                double dy = fabs(center_y - (yy + 0.5)) / ratio_h_half;
                double center_x = (i + 0.5) * ratio_w;
                double w0 = dy * dy; // pre-calc part of w
                int xx_start = (int)floor(i * ratio_w);
                int xx_stop = (int)ceil((i + 1) * ratio_w);
                for (int xx = xx_start; xx < xx_stop; xx++) {
                    double dx = fabs(center_x - (xx + 0.5)) / ratio_w_half;
                    double w = sqrt(w0 + dx * dx);
                    if (w >= 1) {
                        // pixel too far
                        continue;
                    }
                    // hermite filter
                    weight = 2 * w * w * w - 3 * w * w + 1;
                    int pos_x = 4 * (xx + yy * width_source);
                    // alpha
                    gx_a += weight * imageData[pos_x + 3];
                    weights_alpha += weight;
                    // colors
                    if (imageData[pos_x + 3] < 255)
                        weight = weight * imageData[pos_x + 3] / 250.0;
                    gx_r += weight * imageData[pos_x];
                    gx_g += weight * imageData[pos_x + 1];
                    gx_b += weight * imageData[pos_x + 2];
                    weights += weight;
                }
            }
            outputData[x2] = (uint8_t)(gx_r / weights);
            outputData[x2 + 1] = (uint8_t)(gx_g / weights);
            outputData[x2 + 2] = (uint8_t)(gx_b / weights);
            outputData[x2 + 3] = (uint8_t)(gx_a / weights_alpha);
        }
    }
}
```

I compile this code to `hermite_resample.wasm` and then load it in my page:

```
var fast_hermite_resampler = null;

(async () => {
               
    const fetchPromise = fetch("/wasm/hermite_resample.wasm");
    const { module, instance } = await WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming(fetchPromise);
    
    fast_hermite_resampler = {
        "resample": (imageData, outputData, width_source, height_source, newWidth, newHeight) => {
            // Convert UInt8ClampedArray to a normal JavaScript array
            const dataArray = Array.from(imageData);
            const outputArray = Array.from(outputData);

            // Allocate memory and copy data
            const dataPtr = instance.exports.__allocArray(dataArray);
            const outputPtr = instance.exports.__allocArray(outputArray);

            // Call the hermite_resample function
            instance.exports.hermite_resample(dataPtr, outputPtr, width_source, height_source, newWidth, newHeight);

            // Copy the result back to the outputs array
            instance.exports.__copyArray(outputPtr, outputArray);

            // Free memory
            instance.exports.__deallocArray(dataPtr);
            instance.exports.__deallocArray(outputPtr);
        }
    }

})();
```

However, later in the code when I want to use resampling, I get the following error:

```
let newWidth = 128;
let newHeight = 128;

var newImageData = new Uint8ClampedArray(newWidth * newHeight * 4);

// ERROR: Uncaught TypeError: instance.exports.__allocArray is not a function
fast_hermite_resampler.resample(oldImageData, newImageData, oldWidth, oldHeight, newWidth, newHeight);
```

How can I use the compiled wasm code to pass two `UInt8ClampedArray` references and run the resampling?

Edit: `console.log(instance.exports)` prints the following:
[image: instance exports]

Comment: Maybe `console.log(instance.exports)` to see what you're working with. By a quick googling, `__allocArray` is an AssemblyScript thing.

Comment: How exactly do you compile the C code?

Comment: And more importantly, why do you expect it to export AssemblyScript primitives?

Comment: @user3840170 I did compile it with [WasmFiddle](https://wasdk.github.io/WasmFiddle/)

Comment: Where are your `__allocArray` and `__deallocArray` methods?

Comment: @dnnagy Well, evidently you don't have `__allocArray` and `__deallocArray` there (since as the comments say, they're provided by AssemblyScript, which is not what you're using). Looking at [this post](https://rob-blackbourn.github.io/blog/webassembly/wasm/array/arrays/javascript/c/2020/06/07/wasm-arrays.html#passing-arrays-to-wasm) you should be able to allocate an array in the WASM `memory`, copy your data to it, and then copy it back.

Comment: Surely you’re not going to copy-paste the WASM output from that fiddle website to production?

Comment: @Dimava does photon have hermite resample? If not, OP might just as well use `drawImage` to resize a canvas.

Comment: seems like the issue with
https://github.com/AssemblyScript/assemblyscript/issues/1433