# Fabricjs HTML5 Canvas: Why are images so poorly resized?

Tags: html, image, html5-canvas, fabricjs

When I add a 775 x 775 image to a fabricjs canvas and resize it down to around 90 x 90, the image greatly loses its quality.

[image: fabricjs canvas iamge]

But if I add that same image as an `<img/>` and scale it down, it retains its quality.

[image: html img]

Why does the canvas image become so low quality? How can I make the canvas image retain it's original quality like the `<img/>` does?

Comment: I reproduced it here. http://jsfiddle.net/pVE33/1/

Comment: I can't reproduce this with your fiddle (on Chrome 33) — https://www.dropbox.com/s/qs9t0bww6eg5bop/Screenshot%202013-11-25%2011.35.47.png

Comment: That's interesting. The images should be the same size. Here's what I see on firefox 25.0 - http://i.imgur.com/QNPMfeC.png

Comment: They are the same size for me too. I just resized it to show that quality is preserved (you can see it in enlarged view). But if the question is "why does scaled-down image look pixelated", that has to do with canvas rendering of a particular browser.

Comment: Yes my question is "why does scaled-down image look pixelated?". Is there no way to get the canvas image to retain its high quality like the html <img/> does?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/18765964/130652

Comment: Did you test is in multiple browsers?

Comment: I can confirm that the image is pixelated when I open the jsfiddle link provided by troq. Using Chrome 33. Have a read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18922880/html5-canvas-resize-downscale-image-high-quality

Answer (score 3):

It should probably go for a comment, but unfortunately I am new here and I can't add comments.
However, to me it looks like antialiasing issue. Canvas is just bunch of pixels - it's up to you whether you do some antialiasing or not. Browsers however do some antialiasing on picture scaling (see here [Disable antialising when scaling images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14068103/disable-antialising-when-scaling-images)).

This question might be a duplicate of:

[Html5 canvas drawImage: how to apply antialiasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861447/html5-canvas-drawimage-how-to-apply-antialiasing)

[HTML5 Canvas and Anti-aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261090/html5-canvas-and-anti-aliasing)

Hope it helps.