# How to compress .png images when exporting from Canvas using toDataURL()?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, png, todataurl

Need to generate .png images that are about ~20k in size using HTML5 canvas. Unfortunately, when creating .pngs using the toDataURL() method, you cannot specify quality like you can with jpegs.

Any ideas for a workaround? toDataURL seems to be the only way to generate images from Canvas and canvas seems to be the best tool for image processing without server interaction. Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think there is any workaround other than sending it back to the server, however [one article](http://blog.import.io/tech-blog/html5-canvas-todataurl-webm-vs-png-vs-jpeg) claims that the quality parameter actually works for PNG.

Comment: Thanks Derek, though I haven't had any luck supplying PNG with a quality parameter yet. This article provides any interesting way to 'step down' images: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761404/how-to-scale-images-on-a-html5-canvas-with-better-interpolation

Comment: PNG is a lossless compression format. You can use compression with jpg or webp but no with pngs.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/toDataURL

Answer (score 3):

There IS a way to have compression for PNG images using lossless zlib deflate process http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Compression.html . There is a library (https://github.com/ShyykoSerhiy/canvas-png-compression) that provides shim for HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() when image type is 'image/png' and enables ability to provide 'quality' as second parameter to HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL() for png.

NOTE that it provides better results(smaller size) only in Chrome. Firefox sometimes has better compression than canvas-png-compression(as for 0.0.3 version).

Answer (score 1):

You can do something by scaling it down and then scaling it up again.

- Scale down by drawing it on a smaller canvas, then get the data url.
- Create an image object set the data url as its source.
- Draw on the original canvas with this img object (obviously inside the onload event callback)
- Find the size ratio of the canvases to give you optimum result by experimenting a bit.

Comment: also this  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18761404/how-to-scale-images-on-a-html5-canvas-with-better-interpolation?lq=1) for better scale down