# Create new thumbnail image from URL

Tags: javascript, image

I have an image with big dimensions and size, for example, I will use this (10MB, 10000x7000 pixels):

> https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/Pizigani_1367_Chart_10MB.jpg).

Can I save that file to a variable, then scale it down to specific size and store as a `base64` code using `javascript` ?
Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19183658/4297364

Comment: excuse me, your answer link just doesn't have the solution for scaling the image

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18765964/4297364