# Pictures with patterns sometimes display strangely

Tags: html, image, distortion

My site is a clothing store, and my partner has complained about the following issue.

The pictures of clothing with more complex patterns (checkerboard for example) displays like this: [image] instead of this:
[image]

I assume the other pictures are also displaying weirdly, but it's just less noticeable. As far as I can tell, it happens most often on Macs.

If anyone has any information about this phenomenon it would be much appreciated.

Comment: It's called the Moiré effect https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called the Moiré effect. From a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern):

> In physics, mathematics, and art, a moiré pattern (/mwɑrˈeɪ/; French:
>   [mwaˈʁe]) is a secondary and visually evident superimposed pattern
>   created, for example, when two identical (usually transparent)
>   patterns on a flat or curved surface (such as closely spaced straight
>   lines drawn radiating from a point or taking the form of a grid) are
>   overlaid while displaced or rotated a small amount from one another.

In context of images the overlaying comes from anti-aliased (in case of upsampling) or averaged pixels (for downsampling).

To resize them properly use high-quality resizing such as bi-cubic interpolation based resampling. Most browser has built-in support for this but certain conditions are affecting which stratgey is selected (bi-cubic or bi-linear), for example for performance reason. The latter is more prone to this effect.

It can be reduced using a canvas to scale down the image. I have an [article here](http://abdiassoftware.com/blog/2013/10/how-to-properly-scale-a-large-image-to-a-smaller-size-using-canvas/) on this topic and an [SO answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861447/html5-canvas-drawimage-how-to-apply-antialiasing) showing a concrete example on how to.

Comment: Your article was a very interesting read. My question is: is the overhead of creating a canvas object for each image worth it? Won't that negatively affect load times?

Comment: @General_Twyckenham it will have very little effect on the load time. If the image has loaded drawing the image to canvas is a rather fast operation. Using step-down twice will not take much time either as each do less in regard to resampling. If non-important images I would probably not bother but if they are for presentation I would either do this or create a different size in f.ex. Photoshop.

Comment: Ok sounds simple enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

It's called a Moire Pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moir%C3%A9_pattern

The best solution is to not resize images, to ensure they're displayed at 1:1 scaling. If not, make differently-sized images using a tool like Photoshop that has better image-resize algorithms that avoid this problem and then use HTML5's `srcset` attribute so the right image is loaded for the right DPI, see here: http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/srcset/w3c-srcset/

Comment: Very interesting. Do you know if php's image resize functions will scale them properly?

Comment: @General_Twyckenham  I don't know, PHP has different image-processing libraries (e.g. GD, Cairo, ImageMagick).