# Resize image using Canvas awkward behavior

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, resize

I want to get a displayed, big image and resize it by drawing it on a canvas.

I found the following fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/v8app/

```
Exisitng
```

This seems to work great since i want to use it to resize images and store them later on.
However, when i try to use it with my already uploaded images i get awkward behavior:

Result with my img:
[image]

Thanks

Link to the image: frankh.ursa.uberspace.de/img/34.png

Comment: When you say "awkward", what does that mean?

Comment: There are more details in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861447/html5-canvas-drawimage-how-to-apply-antialiasing/17862644#17862644 Could you provide a working link to the original image? (the link first posted requires authentication).

Comment: Thanks in advance - here the link: http://frankh.ursa.uberspace.de/img/34.png btw - the problem is not the quality but the fact the the image is also rendered in the background

Comment: Could the Problem ne that the image has transparency and since the canvas is drawn in many steps the last step doesnt overwrite all The space?

Comment: solution is to use third canvas :)
http://jsfiddle.net/wasikuss/v8app/858/