# Canvas linear downscaling

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas

im trying to do a downscale of an image using canvas to later use the data for a hash compare. however i noticed that the canvas (or at least the simple code i use) uses no mipmap filter resulting in very sharp result and makes the test against another existing hash fail (downscaling the image in gimp using linear works as expected). the code i use to downscale is

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = width; canvas.height = height;

var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height);

return context.getImageData(0, 0, width, height).data;
```

this results in this image (left) to the expected (right)

[image: canvas vs gimp]

how can i get the canvas to downscale linear?

Comment: Currently as far as I know there is no way to control how Canvas scales images. For now, your best bet is to do it manually, i.e. write (or find) your own downscaling algorithm.

Comment: damn thats too bad. i was happy that i found a small and very fast solution and hoped for an option like in opengl or directx. thanks for your info. i will start to work on something now instead of searching for a solution for how i do it now

Comment: You can set the context renderer to use smoothing via the flag             `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;` or for firefox `ctx.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = true;`Most hardware configurations that I have used appear to use Bilinear interpolation when this flag is true.

Comment: i think thats only for upscaling but i tested it anyway with no change sadly

Comment: I guess you could create your own pseudo-mipmap -- basically a spritesheet image containing downscaled versions of your image.

Answer (score 1):

The [new canvas draft](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#image-smoothing) specify a way to set re-sampling/interpolation for the canvas. The current method is always bi-linear, or nearest-neighbor if `imageSmoothingEnabled = false` (both methods are for both up-scaling and down-sampling). The new property is called `imageSmoothingQuality`:

> context . imageSmoothingQuality [ = value ]

The [value can be](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#imagesmoothingquality) "`low`", "`medium`" and "`high`" (for example something like bi-cubic/Lanczos). However, no browsers has yet implemented this at the moment of writing this and the actual algorithms used for each value is not mandated.

The alternative approaches is to manually re-sample when you need changes above 50% using multiple steps, or to implement a re-sampling algorithm.

**[Here is an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17861447/html5-canvas-drawimage-how-to-apply-antialiasing/17862644#17862644)** of multiple steps to achieve bi-cubic quality level (and avoids initial CORS problems), as well as **[one showing the Lanczos algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3223466/1693593)** (need CORS requirements to be met).

In addition to that you can apply [sharpening convolution](https://jsfiddle.net/epistemex/v5zp7y2r/) to compensate for some of the lost sharpness.

Comment: Is this an April fools' joke or is this a come-back ? Anyway glad to read good contents.