# HTML canvas image is far lower quality than original image. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a simple HTML document with an image and a canvas element. The image src is just some high quality image found online, just to illustrate my point. When I try to draw the image onto the canvas, the resulting canvas image is very pixelated and low quality. I can't seem to figure out why. 
Similar questions have been asked here, but I couldn't find an answer that seemed to solve the problem. If someone finds another post with  a working answer, please let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Here is the JSfiddle with the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/vey309b0/5/

**HTML:**

```
<p>the original image:</p>
<img id="img_cam" src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/k8IX2Mkf0Jo/U4ze2gNn7CI/AAAAAAAA7xg/iKxa6bYITDs/s0/HOT+Balloon+Trip_Ultra+HD.jpg" width="400">
<p>the canvas with drawn image:</p>
<canvas id="imgcanvas" width="400"></canvas>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("imgcanvas");
var img_can = document.getElementById("img_cam");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var imgWidth = img_can.width;
var imgHeight = img_can.height;
canvas.width = imgWidth;
canvas.height = imgHeight;
ctx.drawImage(img_can, 0, 0, imgWidth, imgHeight);
```

Comment: Because the actual image dimensions are 3,840px × 2,160px and you are distorting it to a width of 400px take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17862644/2311317

Comment: so I should reduce it in steps by creating multiple canvas elements, each with a size say 1/2 of the previous?

Comment: Correctimondo, or edit the image in an editor and reduce it before use.

Comment: https://github.com/nodeca/pica

Comment: thanks for all the help! May I ask, if I am putting an image into the <img> tag with such a high resolution, and then reducing it to a width of 400px, why is the image showing up in high resolution, and the canvas element is not? Am I not reducing both of them in the same way. Wouldn't the image element undergo the same distortion as the canvas element?

Comment: The browser does it own thing with the image in the image tag, canvas is allowing you full control and is awaiting your instructions :)

Answer (score 10):

Set the width and the height of the canvas to the `naturalWidth` and `naturalHeight` of the image, and then use CSS to constrain the canvas size.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("imgcanvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var img_can = document.getElementById("img_cam");
img_can.onload = function() {
  canvas.width = this.naturalWidth;
  canvas.height = this.naturalHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
};
img_can.src = img_can.getAttribute('data-src');
```

```html
<p>
the original image:
</p>
<img id="img_cam" data-src="https://4.bp.blogspot.com/-k8IX2Mkf0Jo/U4ze2gNn7CI/AAAAAAAA7xg/iKxa6bYITDs/s0/HOT+Balloon+Trip_Ultra+HD.jpg" width="400">
<p>
the canvas with drawn image:
</p>
<canvas id="imgcanvas" style="width:400px;"></canvas>
```

You should also really be doing this work in an `onload` listener on the img tag.

Comment: This does not work here. Or answer his question

Comment: @pokeybit - works for me, and it does answer the question. The quality of the canvas image is not perfect, but it's far superior to the OPs JSFiddle. It's probably not working because the work isn't being done in an `onload` of the image, I'll remedy this. (The second time you load the snippet it works because of caching).

Comment: Firefox here. It looks shocking

Comment: Firefox here, it does not look perfect, but it's about 100x improvement (subjective) over the original JSFiddle

Comment: I take it back, on a retina display it looks fine, on non-retina, you're right, it's terrible.

Comment: I'd go with the duplicate's solution :) +1 for effort

Comment: how would I go about implementing `onload`?

Comment: @DavidCoco - see the edit, probably should go with the dupe, though.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for all the help!