# Drawing a Canvas into a smaller Canvas not working

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

For a Project I want to take the content of a canvas (Called SAVE_CV) and display it in another, smaller canvas.

Some things that I am aware of so far that could be causing me problems: resizing a canvas clears its content, the JS-size of a canvas is different from the CSS-size.

I want the smaller canvas to be 500px wide and appropriately high.

```
function restoreTaggingCV() {
    var cv = document.getElementById( 'taggingCV' );
    var ctx = cv.getContext( "2d" );
    var styleHeight = SAVE_CV.height * 500 / SAVE_CV.width;
    ctx.drawImage(SAVE_CV, 0, 0, cv.width, cv.height);
}
```

This is my Code so far. Whenever I try to resize the smaller canvas appropriately it only gives me a blank canvas with nothing in it. I tried to set the size with `"cv.height = X" and "cv.style.height = styleHeight + 'px'"` but neither worked. Also I would love to set the width of the canvas using CSS.

Appreciate any help.

**EDIT**
I want the image in a picture because later I want the user to mark areas in the smaller version which I then want to use to create individual imaged from the big version. I want to visualise thise area to the user. I probably could do all this by using an image and putting divs over it or something but I just fell more comfident using a canvas since I am pritty new to HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `CanvasRenderingContext2d.prototype.scale` method. It sets the scale factor of the canvas and renders anything in the current state with it's dimensions multiplied by the factor.

So before you use the `drawImage` function, you scale the context appropriately (in this case, down). For example:

```
context.save();
context.scale(0.5, 0.5);
context.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);
context.restore();
```

This would render the canvas on the context at 0.5 times it's current size. See in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJDrX/) how I used it to mirror a larger canvas onto a smaller, separate one.

Answer (score 0):

Canvas objects don't like to be resised. After drawing Your image simply convert it toDataURL() and set as image source. They You may resize image as you want.

`$img.attr('src',canvas.toDataURL());`

Comment: But I would love to have it in a canvas. Adding some explaination why to post.

Comment: It simply can't be done, as far as I noticed. Every time You try to resize canvas, it content dissapears. That's the way it works...

Comment: But thats not a bad thing, I want the resize the canvas and then draw into it. So it's okay when the resize clears the canvas.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas ... still uses my method, sorry :)