# how to change background color of icon in chrome extension notification

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i have problem with chrome extension rich notification. My problem is about icon. I'm getting icons from a server. But thesee icon's sizes are 120 * 60
Width: 120
Height: 60

My notification: [image]

But i need 120 * 120. I tried to change height but failed. So i thought i can change background color. Current icon background color is gray. I need to change it to white or transparent. I searched but i couldnt find. I hope you can help me about resize height or change background color of chrome extension notification icon. 
Thanks.

Comment: @wOxxOm Please make that into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing in the [notifications API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications).

Use [Canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial/Using_images) API ([some examples](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2303690/3959875)) to manually create 120x120 px colored background, combine it with the downsized image and then output it in the notification.