# Canvas shrink alternative

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

I am looking for an alternative to shrink my images. Until now I shrinked my images with a canvas method like here:  [Resizing an image in an HTML5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas) 
The problem is that this method is not supported by older Browser-versions, so I am looking for a method which shrinks the image (not just scale it) without Canvas. 
Is there another solution or is it impossible to do this without Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

I just do not set a width on height on an image and inmy css i wil have img {max-width:100%}

Comment: No that just scales it not shrink it, so it does not shrink the file size.

Comment: What if you use a different image in the media querie?

Comment: How do you mean? Can yu

Comment: Can you make an example or explain it better? ;)

Comment: Yeah for example you will have a normal image as a background then in your media querie just google which one to use the in the same css you just call the same backgrouns image but the scaled down smaller version here's a nifty tool https://imageresizer.io/

Comment: Did I get it right: This Plugin can shrink my images realy, so that the file size would be lower?

Comment: That is correct so for each media querie you put the same image but a smaller one which will reduce the website speed.

Comment: Ok thanks but you mean that it improve the website speed so it makes it faster right?

Comment: Yes so its much better to use a smaller image in responsive view will load faster

Comment: Hi sorry. I looked again and saw that this Plugin is not download able, you have to send an url to it but I want to write it into my code. Someone another solution?

Comment: Until responsive images become part of the standard, html5 canvas is the only element that can actually manipulate image pixels. Alternatively, you can use 3rd party image libraries that read the image file and manipulate the content. **We don't recommend libraries on Stackoverflow**, but you can Google both server-side & client-side image libraries