# image resize before uploaded

Tags: php, laravel

Hi Friend's need help how to reduce the image size before uploading ans each image have 5MB this is my code

```
public static function upload_file($input, $path="uploads")
{
    $files = array();  
    if($input){
        foreach ($input as $file) {
            if ($file){
                $fileSize = $file->getSize();              
                $destinationPath = base_path() . "/$path/";
                if(!file_exists($destinationPath)){
                    mkdir($destinationPath);
                }
                $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
                $fileName = ServicewebHelper::gen_uuid() . '.' . $extension;
                $file_object['fileName'] = $fileName;
                $file_object['filePath'] = "/$path/" . $fileName;
                $file_object['fileSize'] = $file->getSize();
                $file_object['fileType'] = $file->getMimeType();
                $file_object['fileExtension'] = $extension;
                $file_object['fileOriginalName'] = $filename;
                $file->move($destinationPath, $destinationPath . $fileName, 0777);
                chmod($destinationPath . $fileName, 0777);
                $files[] = $file_object;
            }
        }
    }
    return $files;
}
```

any one please help me how to resize the image when before uploading

Comment: [Intervention Image](http://image.intervention.io/) is a good library, IMO. That's it.

Comment: just now i have try but not working

Comment: @Chay22 I think Invention is not what he wants, since upload size can be limited. I presume that this person also wants to speed up the upload time.

Comment: @sivakumar.s This has to be performed in Javascript. Have a look to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303690/resizing-an-image-in-an-html5-canvas)

Comment: this way i have try it

Comment: $file = Image::make($fileName)->resize(320, 240);
                     $file->move($destinationPath, $destinationPath . $fileName, 0777);

Comment: but not working