# How to avoid HTML Canvas auto-stretching

Tags: html, canvas, drawimage

I have the following piece of HTML:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #c{width:200px;height:500px}
</style>
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = new Image();
    i.onload = function () {
        var ctx = document.getElementById('c').getContext('2d');
        ctx.drawImage(i, 0, 0);
    }
    i.width = i.height = 20; // actual size of square.png
    i.src = 'square.png';
</script>
```

The issue is that the drawn image is automatically stretched (resized) proportionally with the size of the canvas. I have tried using all available parameters (`drawImage(i, 0, 0, 20, 20, 0, 0, 20, 20)`) and that didn't help.

What is causing my drawing to stretch and how can I prevent that?

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Found my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretch-when-using-css-but-normal-with-old-width-and-height-propert

Comment: Promote your comment to a real answer for the good of the next person to come looking, and I'll give you a cookie (or an upvote, whichever I have on me).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You need the `width` and `height` attributes in the canvas element. They specify the coordinate space for the canvas. Apparently, it defaults to a canvas of a 2:1 aspect ratio, which your CSS is skewing into a square.

Answer (score 28):

It's worth noting that the Width and Height attributes of canvas are *not* like the old school <img> width and height attributes. They are not a substitute for CSS. They specify how many pixels the pixel buffer in the canvas itself should have, and if you don't apply a size to it with css, css will imply it's size from that shape of that pixel buffer. Setting the element's size in css does not set the size of the pixel buffer - it resizes it. From a CSS perspective, a <canvas> is entirely the same thing as an <img>.

Answer (score 11):

Ok, a little bit simplier (and lighter) than JQuery is .. JAVASCRIP ITSELF of course !

If you need to change dynamicaly your canvas dimensions, just use:

```
document.getElementById('yourcanvasid').setAttribute('width', aWidth);
document.getElementById('yourcanvasid').setAttribute('height', aHeight);
```

Comment: document.getElementById('yourcanvasid').width = aWidth also does this

Answer (score 8):

If you're using JQuery, you shouldn't set the CSS (as the commenters above mentioned). You need to set the attribute so:

```
$("canvas").attr('width', aWidth);
$("canvas").attr('height', aHeight);
```

works great.

Answer (score -1):

I found it easier to just put a while loop waiting for timeout within my animation loop, For example:

```
function animate() {
    c.clearRect(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    ryuji.draw();
    ryuji.update();
    let now = Date.now();
    then = now + (1000 / fps);
    while (Date.now() < then) {

    }
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
```