# Grid drawn using a <canvas> element looking stretched

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, grid

I'm trying to draw a grid on a `<canvas>` element with the ultimate goal of making a [Go board](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/df/Go_game_example.png).

For some reason the grid is looking stretched, with the lines being thicker than 1 pixel and the spacing being completely wrong. It doesn't even start in the `(10,10)` position..

It would be great if someone could take a look at tell me what I'm doing wrong.

### http://jsfiddle.net/h2yJn/

[image]

Comment: Found the answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretch-when-using-css-but-normal-with-old-width-and-height-propert and here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892041/how-to-avoid-html-canvas-auto-stretching

Comment: This https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/135207/210612 may help too

Answer (score 36, accepted):

I've found the problem. I was setting the dimensions of the `<canvas>` using CSS, when you actually have to set the width and height attributes. This was causing it to be stretched/skewed.

```
var canvas = $('<canvas/>').attr({width: cw, height: ch}).appendTo('body');
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/h2yJn/66/

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please try it outside jsfiddle, maybe jsfiddle is applying some linear transformation.

Also please make sure that you add 0.5 everywhere to both x and y coordinates. Alternatively, you can apply translate(0.5, 0.5) to shift all coordinates by half a pixel.

Comment: I'm getting the same result on jsbin.com, I'm pretty sure I've added 0.5px everywhere I could possibly add it. That wouldn't cause such dramatic effects anyway though would it?

Comment: Another way is just to start a cycle from 0.5 like this: `for (var i = 0.5; i < fieldSize+1; i+=40) {...`