# How to make HTML Canvas clickable grid (that returns cell to match array element?)

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, canvas

Trying to build the Game of Life here with React JS. I have a 2-dimensional array that holds the state of the grid. Every element, which is an array, represents a row and a sub-element is either 0 or 1 (dead or alive).

I want to use HTML Canvas to draw the grid based on this array and also add a click function that returns the matching element in the array so I can write a function to change it to 0 or 1 based on an algorithm.

I have a general idea how to draw a grid, also checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11735856/draw-grid-table-on-canvas-html5)

But i am not sure whether this is the way to do it so I can identify each cell with a click. And also stuck on how I can return the cell to match the array element. Anyone can help me with this?

I am also aware of [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9140101/creating-a-clickable-grid-in-a-web-browser), but the answers are implementations with HTML or SVG, I am looking for a canvas implementation.

Comment: I suggest https://bitbucket.org/nikola_l/visual-js

Answer (score 2):

First of all you have to handle the click event. Here you can find a good description of how: [How do I add a simple onClick event handler to a canvas element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880279/how-do-i-add-a-simple-onclick-event-handler-to-a-canvas-element).

Furthermore, you just use the x and y of the clicked point to determine what tile has been clicked. Lets say you have 10 x 10 tiles with the height and width of 10 px.

If the user clicks the coordnate 67,12 you can divide x and y by ten, and round it off to know which elelemt in your 2d array that represents it.