# Why do my HTML5 rectangles appear zoomed in?

Tags: html, graphics, canvas, image-scaling

Following http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-rectangles/, I have drawn some rectangles side-by-side on a canvas. The problem is that they appear greatly zoomed in; at a zoom of 1.0 they appear approximately five times their original size; they appear correctly sized (if fuzzy around the borders) at a zoom of around 0.16.

I expect I could get a workaround by making the pixel dimensions of the canvas much greater and zooming out, but what is the proper way to get a 1:1 scaling on a canvas? The canvas is styled to width and height of 100%, and the body has a margin of 0. Manually setting the canvas's width and height to the height and width of the window does not alter this behavior.

TIA,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

the problem is, you set the width and height of the *style* for the canvas. You need to set the width and height attributes, not the css style. so something like:

```
<canvas id='mycanvas' width='800' height='600'></canvas>
```

More info in a similar question: [Canvas is stretched when using CSS but normal with "width" / "height" properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretch-when-using-css-but-normal-with-old-width-and-height-proper)