# Why is the canvas circle not looking like a circle?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have a very simple code that should draw a circle, but its not looking like one, and not at the right position The coordinates are all somewhat shifted. The canvas is set to `style="width: 600px; height: 600px;"`. I tried it on chrome and safari - looks the same so it's not a browser bug.
So my questions are (there is probably one answer for both):

1. If I am putting the center at (100, 100), why is the circle not at an equal distance from the left border, that it is from the top border?
2. Why is the (300, 300) point out of the canvas, and not in the center?

The code:

```
var context = document.getElementById('c').getContext("2d");
context.fillStyle = 'black';
context.fill();
context.beginPath();
context.arc(100, 100, 30, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
context.stroke();
```

How it looks:
[image]

## Edit

According to the comment I found out that writing `<canvas id="myCanvas" style="width: 578px; height: 200px;"></canvas>` is causing this problem, and writing `<canvas id="myCanvas" width="578" height="200"></canvas>` solves it. Anyone knows why?

Comment: Do you have the `width` and `height` attributes set on the `<canvas>` tag? They influence the size differently than the css `width`/`height` properties.

Comment: @DCoder I have this code: `<canvas id="c" style="width:600px; height: 600px; background-color: yellow"></canvas>`

Comment: @MaggiQall Why 3? PI is half a circle (equal to 180 degrees). So 2*PI is a whole circle - 360 degrees

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is documented in the [HTML5 Canvas spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#attr-canvas-width).

The *HTML attributes* `width="x" height="y"` describe the *drawing area* of the canvas and default to `300 × 150 px`. As a side-effect, they describe the default visible size of the canvas.

The *CSS properties* `width: x; height: y;` set on the canvas can stretch/compact that drawing area, but they don't change its size.

In your case, the browser stretches the default drawing area (`300 × 150 px`) to meet the given CSS of `600 × 600 px`.

Answer (score 2):

This example shows how to draw a circle on canvas: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/

Also, you need to set the `width` and `height` attributes on the canvas element rather as a `style` attribute like so:

```
<canvas id="c" width="600" height="600" style="background-color:yellow;"></canvas>
```

Comment: Yeah I just found that out too according to the comment. Do you have any idea why?

Comment: go to this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2588181/canvas-is-stretch-when-using-css-but-normal-with-old-width-and-height-proper